# Turn off #available(OSX 10.10, *) if that's your target?

Tags: swift

I use `containsString` in my app. My app has targets for 10.10 and nothing older. Swift complains and suggests introducting this horrible syntax...

```
        if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
            if !NSString(string: line).containsString(" ") { continue }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

Well since this app won't run on anything earlier, this code is useless. Is there a way to turn this off globally? I don't want or need it.

Comment: What is your deployment target? Could be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: 10.10 is the OS X deployment target. There is no iOS target (yet). For an experiment I changed that to 9.0, which definitely has containsString, but the error did not go away.

Comment: I doubt iOS is what is causing this. Could be an issue in current compiler. Make sure to open a bug report with Apple as soon as possible.

Comment: Done! With screen snaps and everything.